Does Haag's theorem lack dynamics?
It is stated that when the degrees of freedom of the Hilbert space in terms of which quantum mechanics is formulated becomes infinite, the unitary equivalence that is ensured by the Stone-von Neumann theorem for a finite number of degrees of freedom does not apply anymore. The infinite number of degrees of freedom in such formulations of quantum mechanics leads to unitarily inequivalent Hilbert spaces. Or so it is claimed. I would like to understand this issue of unitary inequivalence.
When you ask people about unitary inequivalence, they direct you to Haag's theorem. So I decided to find some text on Haag's theorem and study it. The first challenge is that it is not so easy to get a proper write-up, but I eventually got a philosophy paper [*]. Although it is philosophy text, I assume that the authors provided a fair rendition of Haag's theorem and a description of its proof.
After studying this theorem I find that the logic of argument escapes me. It does not seem to include the dynamics. Therefore, I would appreciate it if somebody can clarify what exactly Haag's theorem is showing and what it has to do with unitary inequivalence.
Let me provide more detail about how I understand the argument or derivation of Haag's theorem as provided in [*]. It is based on the calculation of a four-point function given by the product of four field operators which is then overlapped by the ground state
$$ \mathcal{M}(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = \langle 0| \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \phi(x_3) \phi(x_4) |0 \rangle . $$
The argument then seems to go that if we start with these field operators in the interaction picture one can show by the judicious application of local unitaries that this four-point function becomes equal to the same four-point function evaluated in a free-field theory without interactions. What I mean by a local unitary is a unitary transformation that is applied to a single field operator
$$ \phi'(x) = \hat{U} \phi(x) . $$
What confuses me is that the four-point function in the interaction picture that is used in the theorem does not really include any interactions. What I would have expected is to see some global unitary that represents the interaction. For example, if we consider the elastic scattering of two input particles and then want to see two output particles, we would define an input state as
$$ |\psi_{\text{in}}(x_3,x_4)\rangle = \phi(x_3) \phi(x_4) |0\rangle , $$
the output state as
$$ \langle \psi_{\text{out}}(x_1,x_2)| = \langle 0| \phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) , $$
so that the scattering is given by
$$ \mathcal{M}(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = \langle \psi_{\text{out}}(x_1,x_2)| U_{\text{global}}|\psi_{\text{in}}(x_3,x_4)\rangle , $$
where $U_{\text{global}}$ is the global unitary representing the evolution of the input state in the presence of the nonlinear interactions, applied to the complete input state and not on the individual field operators. For such a calculation, the local unitaries would not be able to unravel the dynamics. Therefore this overlap cannot be shown to be equivalent to a free field calculation.
So, what am I missing?

Some clarification is needed for what I mean by dynamics. Perhaps a simple analogy will help. If I want to calculate an expectation value of product of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ in statistics, I would express it as
$$ \langle X Y \rangle = \int xy f_{XY}(x,y)\ dxdy , $$
where $f_{XY}(x,y)$ is the joint probability function. Without this function the integral would be trivial. The left-hand side is just a heuristic way to represent this expression.
By analogy in QFT, I can express the 2-point function in terms of a path integral expression as
$$ \langle \phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\rangle = \int \phi(x_1)\phi(x_2) \exp(iS[\phi])\ \mathcal{D}[\phi] , $$
where $S[\phi]$ is the action of the theory that contains the dynamics (interaction terms). For other n-point functions, one would have $n$ fields in the integral multiplying the exponential. The left-hand side is just a heuristic way to represent the n-point in analogy to how it is heuristically represented in the statistical expression above. From this functional integral one can now generate all the Feynman diagrams that represents the dynamics that is responsible for producing the full n-point function. One cannot compute this dynamics (all the Feynman diagrams) from the heuristic expression which just contains the product of field operators overlapped on both sides by the ground state.
So I don't understand how the apparently heuristic expression for the n-point function in Haag's theorem include the same dynamics that we have in the path integral.

I have looked at other questions about Haag's theorem. None of then seems to address this issue with the dynamics.
[*] Earman, John, and Doreen Fraser. "Haag’s theorem and its implications for the foundations of quantum field theory." Erkenntnis 64.3 (2006): (link)

Nitpick: Your first sentence is not correct; the dimensionality of the Hilbert space in the SvN case is also necessarily infinite-dimensional. The problem arises from the infinitely many DoF, roughly speaking.

@TobiasFünke, OK I've edited the question, but I really understand what's the difference.  Doesn't the degrees of freedom determine the number of element in a basis of the Hilbert space?

No. For a spinless single particle in 1D the CCR reads $[X,P]=i$ and as operators this relation can only hold on an infinite dimensional space.

@TobiasFünke, not to put too fine a point on it, you start the statement with "... single particle in 1D ..." Doesn't this mean that it represents a one-dimensional system? What exactly is infinite-dimensional about this space?

Well, e.g. the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb R)$, where you have the Schrödinger representation of the CCR, is infinite-dimensional.

@TobiasFünke, thanks. I think I understand it now. Although the harmonic oscillator is a one-dimensional system, it has infinitely many solutions.

Yes, exactly. The SvN cares about the number of elements which you build the CCR from, roughly speaking, see e.g.nlab and the link to Haag's theorem therein.

You're mixing up different things.
First, there's the interaction picture, which means the following: if you write your Hamiltonian as $H=H_1+H_2$, then correlation functions satisfy
$$
\langle \phi(x_1)\cdots\phi(x_n)\rangle_H\equiv \langle \hat\phi(x_1)\cdots\hat\phi(x_n)e^{i\int H_2\mathrm dt}\rangle_{H_1}
$$
where on the l.h.s. states evolve according to the full Hamiltonian, and on the r.h.s. they evolve according to $H_1$ only, and the effect of $H_2$ is captured by the exponential. The two sets of operators are related via
$$
\hat\phi(x)=e^{iH_1t}\phi(x)e^{-iH_1t}
$$
This is true for any splitting of $H$ into two parts, but is specially useful if $H_1$ is quadratic, since we then know how to evaluate the r.h.s. explicitly.
Second, there's Haags theorem, which says that the unitary $e^{iH_1t}$ is not well defined.
The interaction picture and Haag's theorem are both true. Physicists are well aware that $e^{iH_1t}$ is not a good operator: it contains counterterms that are formally infinite. And we know how to deal with this, just regulate the theory. The regulated theory is not subject to Haag, since it is either non-unitary, or it breaks translation invariance, or it does something else -- in any case the axioms of Haag no longer hold.
So, Haag neither contains nor lacks dynamics. Its only goal is to explain to mathematicians something that physicists have known for almost a century now. Which is: the naive way one would like to do things in QFT is not mathematically rigorous, and one has to work harder. No more, no less.
The reason you are struggling to find physics texts that discuss Haag is that physicists do not care about Haag. It has nothing to teach us, and no implications for our work. Seven years before Haag published his theorem, Schwinger successfully used QFT to compute the electron anomalous moment. These days, we know the value of this constant to fifteen or so digits, and it perfectly matches measurements. Who cares if a mathematician tells us that if this formalism still lacks a satisfying mathematical framework. Well, some people do care, but mostly just mathematicians.

Thank you for the answer. The possible effect of the counter term gives me something to think about. However, I don't think Haag theory is contingent on such effects. So it still does not explain to me the appearance of dynamics in the n-point function. The right-hand side of your first equation with the exponentiated $H_2$ doesn't make sense to me. Is it just a heuristic expression representing the equivalent path integral expression? Or where does the exponential factor come from? Or are you saying "the naive way ..." is without the explicit dynamics as one would have in QFT?

@flippiefanus 1) The r.h.s. of my equation is a rigorous theorem in QM, it is not a heuristic expression. It is not a theorem in QFT precisely because of divergences. But it does hold once you regulate the theory. In the unregulated theory it is indeed heuristic. 2) You keep using the word "dynamics", presumably in a nonstandard sense, because it is not clear which part you're confused about. The standard usage is, say, Dyson-Schwinger (which has the same issues as anything else: it is only a rigorous theorem once you regulate, again due to Haag if you will). What do you mean by "dynamics"?

I've added some clarification in the question.

@flippiefanus (1/2) Thanks. My impression is that you either are unaware that the operator formalism exists, or that you regard it as an informal way to compute path integrals. You do not need path integrals to define/compute correlation functions: the expression $\langle\phi_1\cdots\phi_n\rangle$ is perfectly fine as is, it is not a heuristic for anything. You can compute it using it path integrals (as in the r.h.s. of your formula), but you don't have to: the l.h.s. has perfectly good meaning by itself, it is a matrix element.

(2/2) In 1d, both the r.h.s. and the l.h.s. are rigorously defined by themselves, independently, and it is a theorem that they agree. In higher d, both sides are mathematically undefined, simply because of our limited ingenuity. Physically, both sides are meaningful separately, and it is again a theorem that they agree. The l.h.s. is not defined as a heuristic expression for the r.h.s. Haag is just one of many theorems that tell us that our current mathematical framework is insufficient to define these things rigorously. It does not say that the operator formalism lacks anything.

I am familiar with the operator formalism. That is what I thought I've shown in terms of the global unitary operator, but perhaps I'm a bit rusted since I usually think in terms of path integrals. Perhaps you can remind me how one can get a scattering process from a product of field operators without applying any global unitaries.

@flippiefanus In order to go from $\langle\phi_1\cdots\phi_n\rangle$ to a scattering amplitude you 1) Fourier transform 2) Multiply by $(p_1^2-m_1^2)\cdots(p_n^2-m_n^2)$ and 3) Take the momenta to be on-shell. In other words, the S-matrix is just the residue of the correlation function in momentum space. You can take this as the definition of S, or give a pseudo-proof a la LSZ, or the more rigorous treatment known as Haag-Ruelle (the canonical reference being part IV in Bogolyubov-Logunov-Oksak-Todorov-Gould, "General principles of quantum field theory").

Thanks. (You now hold the official record for the shortest derivation of the LSZ formula.) Anyway, there are still things I don't understand as well as I hoped I would. But I'll probably have to address that in a separate question.

It is worth stressing that the practical impact of Haag's theorem  on QFT is, in fact,  negligible because QFT is plagued by other practically much more serious problems arising from the assumptions that (self)interactions are local, i.e., described by products of fields at a given event of the spacetime.
However this form of locality is not part of the hypotheses of Haag theorem, so the problem of renormalization  appears as a disjoint problem with respect to the issues raised by Haag's theorem.
In practice, all computations of interacting QFT  are made perturbatively and that locality problem arises immediately. It  covers, or better obscures, any theoretical problem generated by Haag's theorem, since the issue of taming the divergent terms of the pertubative series is much more urgent to produce predictions to be compared with experimental data.
Nevertheless all the perturbative procedure adopts an ideal theoretical model (the perturbative approach is to be thought as an approximation of it) which may be based on the very assumptions at the ground of Haag's theorem. (With the caveat I disccuss below). This abstract model is a direct extension of the one adopted in standard Quantum Mechanics when dealing with scattering processes.  In that sense, Haag's theorem has some impact on the construction of the theory and deserves to be considered.
The Haag theorem, in its extened formulation, assumes
(a) covariance of fields under corresponding  unitary representations of the Poincaré group (*),
(b) irreducibility of the CCR representations,
(c) uniqueness of corresponding Poincaré invariant states, the vacuum states which are also required to be
(d) existence of vacua: states of minimal (non negative) energy of the two theories.
In principle these requirements are valid for both a free theory and an interacting theory: in that sense a theory which includes dynamics. Hence Haag's theorem does not lack of dynamics.
Finally, it is assumed that
(e) there is a unitary map which connect the field operators at any given time.
Under these assumptions, Haag's theorem proves that, if one of the two representation of the CCR is the free theory, then
(1) the two representations of CCR are unitary equivalent in the spacetime (not only at fixed time);
(2) the unitary map also transforms the free vacuum to the interacting vacuum**.
This result, in turn, implies that all expectation values and probabilities that one obtains out of the free theory are the same as for the interacting theory: The two theories are practically indistinguishable: The free theory and any interacting theory are not physically distinguishable!
I stress that the LSZ formalism do not assume all the theoretical hypotheses of Haag theorem: it is not supposed that there exists a unitary map which transforms the free field operators to the interacting field operators at any fixed time. Equivalence of the two representations of CCR only takes place asymptotically (at large time) and just in a weak sense (referring to matrix elements).
From this perspective, in principle, there is a theoretical way to avoid the problem with the Haag theorem.
I do not know if this way out is conclusive or other issues pop out.
In any cases, as I stressed at the beginning of this answer, this is is practically quite irrelevant, since also the LSZ formalism must face the renormalization problem.

(*) In the initial step these requirements are just referred to unitary representations of the Euclidean group of the rest space at any given time $t$ of an inertial reference frame. These hypotheses are already sufficient to prove that the two vacua are mapped to each other by the unitary map which transforms the field operators to each other.
In a second step, it is also supposed that the said representations extend to the whole orthochronous Poincaré group, the vacua are fixed under them.

Haag's theorem indeed only talks about the n-point functions (Wightman functions) of the fields, and yet it is about dynamics.
The short answer to the question is: Of course Haag's theorem knows about the dynamics - the n-point functions involve fields $\phi(\vec x,t)$ at arbitrary times $t$ and $\phi(\vec x,t_1)$ and $\phi(\vec x,t_2)$ are of course related by the time evolution operator of the theory ("the dynamics") between $t_1$ and $t_2$. So knowing $\langle \prod_i \phi(x_i)\rangle$ for arbitrary $x_i$ certainly tells you something about the dynamics. More generally, when we write $\phi(x) = \phi(\vec x,t)$, the dynamics are already in there when we claim to know the field for all times $t$.
This is a point rarely stressed in the usual introductory treatments of QFT, but in the framework of axiomatic QFT in terms of the Wightman axioms (which is the setting in which Haag's theorem is actually a rigorous theorem), a quantum field theory is fully defined by its n-point functions. This is the Wightman reconstruction theorem: A set of n-point functions already defines the QFT, in that all quantum field theories with the same n-point functions are unitarily equivalent in the following sense:
For two theories with Hilbert spaces $H_1,H_2$ and scalar fields $\phi_1,\phi_2$ with vacua $\lvert 0\rangle_1,\lvert 0\rangle_2$ and Poincaré representations $U_1,U_2$ on $H_1,H_2$, there is a unitary operator $V : H_1\to H_2$ such that $\phi_2 = V\phi_1V^{-1}$, $U_2 = VU_1 V^{-1}$ and $\lvert 0\rangle_2 = V\lvert 0\rangle_1$. Note that since time translation is part of the Poincaré group, this in particular means that the time evolution operators and Hamiltonians of both theories are related by a unitary operator, and together with the vacuum being the same this means they have the same dynamics. For details on Wightman reconstruction, see e.g. chapter 3-4 of "PCT, Spin, Statistics and all that" by Streater and Wightman.
Also, the question sets up scattering theory wrongly: The particle states we scatter are not created by the interacting fields $\phi(x_i)$ in the manner suggested there. They are instead asymptotic states created by a "free" field in the infinite past and future. Correctly defining this "free" field on the same space as the interacting field is precisely one of the issues Haag's theorem reveals to be more difficult than one would imagine, since the standard texts use the interacting picture to define it - but the partial time evolution operator of the interacting picture is a unitary equivalence between this "free" and the interacting field, and Haag's theorem forbids its existence. For the correct construction of asymptotic particle states in the axiomatic framework, one has to employ more a subtle construction known as Haag-Ruelle scattering theory. For details on Haag-Ruelle theory, see Reed's and Simon's "Methods of mathematical physics", volume 3.
The relation between the scattering amplitudes of asymptotic particles states and n-point functions is given (both in the axiomatic and the "normal" approach) by the LSZ formula - we can compute all scattering amplitudes in terms of the n-point functions of the field. Even without the Wightman reconstruction theorem, this shows the n-point functions have to know about the dynamics, otherwise how could we compute the result of scattering by computing the n-point functions?
The powerful thing about Haag's theorem is now that it provides a kind of inverse to Wightman reconstruction: If you have two fields $\phi_0$ and $\phi_1$ that are related at some time $t_0$ as $\phi_1 = V\phi_0V^{-1}$ by some unitary operator $V$ and $\phi_0$ is a free field (i.e. has the n-point functions of a free field), then $\phi_1$ is a free field, too.
If we think about it in terms of the n-point functions, this shouldn't actually be too surprising: The n-point functions of a free field are, in diagrammatic terms, just disconnected straight lines, i.e. all the non-zero n-point functions are products of the 2-point functions, so the free field is fully defined by its 2-point function (which tells you the only parameter the theory of a single free field has, its mass). But in fact if a field has a two-point function that looks like the two-point function of a free field, it is a free field (this is called the Jost-Schroer theorem) in the sense that all its n-point functions are those of the free field. The unitary operator at time $t_0$ in Haag's theorem (such as the alleged interaction picture operator in standard texts) makes the two-point functions of the fields equal at time $t$, and so really already makes the fields both free fields.
For a modern overview over Haag's theorem and the issues associated with it with many pointers to other literature, I recommend Klaczynski's doctoral thesis "Haag's theorem in renormalisable quantum field theories
".

Thank you for the answer. It provides me with much to think about, but it does not address my confusion. The n-point functions that are referred to by Haag don't seem to be the same thing as we have in quantum field theory. What you mention about the time evolution of a single field operator is basically what I explained in terms of the local unitary. It just gives the propagator. Equipped with only these propagators, one cannot reproduced the full dynamics as seen in the expansion of an arbitrary n-point function in terms of Feynman diagrams. If one can, please show me the detail.

BTW, I am current reading through the thesis you reference at the end, but there are some dubious proofs in it that makes we question the value of this document. For instance, these is a "proof" of Claim 7.4 in which it is stated that because $[A,B]=0$ it follows that $AB|0\rangle=0$, which is obviously not true (for example, one can consider two creation operators).

@flippiefanus 1. I don't follow your objection - as I mention, the LSZ formula reduces the computation of scattering amplitudes to the computation of the n-point functions of the interacting field w.r.t. the interacting vacuum. This is the core of every intro to QFT, and these n-point functions are exactly what appears in Wightman reconstruction. I'm not sure where we disagree. 2. I don't see a "claim 7.4", but if you mean claim 1.10, you need to read a little more carefully - because $j\lvert 0\rangle = 0$, the first term of the commutator vanishes anyway, so the second term vanishes, too.

I've added a clarification. The issue is not the fact that the n-point functions represent all the scattering amplitudes in QFT. I know that. (However, I'm not so sure that the Wightman reconstruction exactly represents the n-point functions of QFT, but that is a different question for another time.) My issue is with the calculation of the n-point function itself and how that calculation is represented in Haag's theorem. How does Haag's calculation reproduce the dynamics?

@flippiefanus 1. See the remark in my answer about the Hamiltonians of both fields being mapped to each other through the condition on the Poincaré representations. 2. Your edit has the wrong setup: In the Wightman axiomatic setting, it is the l.h.s. that exists rigorously - the fields are operator-valued distributions so that $\phi(f)$ is an operator for all Schwartz functions $f$, and the n-point functions are $W(f_i) = \langle 0\vert \prod_i \phi(f_i)\vert 0\rangle$. This is not a heuristic, it's a proper and rigorous definition.

It's the path integral that's only a heuristic, since it does not exist rigorously. For rigorous work on the path integral for fields, see "Quantum Physics" by Glimm and Jaffe, but really for the rigorous setting of Haag's theorem you cannot argue with path integrals at all.

So are you saying that the Feynman diagrams that we can produce via the path integral are all just heuristics? Isn't it then amazing that these heuristics make such successful predictions? How can I calculate such predictions from $W(f_i)$ as you defined it? I've seen the definitions of these operator valued distributions, but I don't see where it is hiding the dynamics? Let's take a simple example, please calculate the 2-point function in scalar theory with a $\phi^3$ interaction. Show me how $W(f_i)$ produces all the self-energy contributions.

@flippiefanus No, I'm not saying that, the Feynman diagrams are a graphical representation of a perturbative expansion of the computation of the n-point functions from a Lagrangian and have nothing to do with using path integrals or not. You're misunderstanding the axiomatic setup (at least the question makes no sense): There is nothing to calculate - the $W(f_1,f_2)$ with $\phi$ as the interacting field of $\phi^3$ theory just is the 2-point function by definition! Again, the Wightman functions are not unusual objects, they are precisely the n-point functions that appear in the LSZ formula.
